# 2D dynamic array seen as trojan?

Tags: c++, oop

I'm trying to create a dynamic 2d array and fill it with values. My antivirus program warns me this is a trojan. I'm using this in another project and I get " bad alloc " error.

```
#include <iostream>
#define MAX_SIZE 10
using namespace std;

    int main() {


        double** W= new double*[MAX_SIZE];
        for(int i=0;i<MAX_SIZE;i++)
        W[i] = new double[MAX_SIZE];

        for (int i=0; i<MAX_SIZE; i++){
            for(int j=0; j<MAX_SIZE;j++){
                W[i][j] = 0.1;
            }
        }


        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Nothing wrong with the code.

Comment: Which antivirus? what trojan does it claim this to be? Does the alert rise only after compilation?

Comment: I forgot deleting W.

Comment: My AV would warn me about my own code (and Windows Defender went so far as to delete them, thanks MS) with no faults or exploit weaknesses. It just sees every executable it does not know about as a threat. I configured it to isolate a folder to work on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot adding delete [] W. It works now. Thanks